# TransferSpreadsheet export: missing 1 row

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a problem with exporting table from Access Table to Excel file.
If I use transferspreadsheet:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, tableName, _
"PathToFile\export.xlsx", True
```

one of the rows from the Access Table is not exported.
But if I right click on the Access table and go to Export -> Excel, this file is with all rows from the table. 
I don't know what the difference is between these 2 ways of exporting.

So does anybody can help me why this one row missing when I use transferspreadsheet?

Comment: So is it consistently the most recent record entered in table? Where do you execute this code - what event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access has this bug, where it takes a little data before the program knows what format each field should be for an excel spreadsheet.

Try setting a sort order before you export the data.  If its a smaller recordset this might fix the issue